# Excel Solver: Decision variables as absolute values

Tags: constraints, excel-2010, solver

I am using the Excel 2010 solver to do some optimizations. Everything is running well except that I would like to run the solver to find a solution such that my decision variables, $A$1:$A$10, are either between 5.1 and 15.3 or between -5.1 and -15.3. I have tried a number of approaches and cannot figure out how to set the constraints. The positive part is OK,

```
 $A$1:$A$10 >= 5.1
 $A$1:$A$10 <= 15.3
```

It is the negative range that I am having difficulty with. I have tried

```
 -$A$1:$A$10 >= 5.1
 -$A$1:$A$10 <= 15.3
```

and even

```
 ABS($A$1:$A$10) >= 5.1
 ABS($A$1:$A$10) <= 15.3
```

but it does not work. I have searched on the net but cannot seem to find anything to help. Is this possible to do, and if so, how would I do it? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Say you wish the decision variable `X` to be either between `5.1` and `15.3` or between `-5.1` and `-15.3`. Replace the decision variable with two new decision variables `XP` and `XN` where `XP` is the positive value of `X`, `XN` is the negative value, and `X = XP – XN`. Then add two constraints:

```
XP + XN >= 5.1
XP + XN <= 15.3
```